# undo a published change in Google tag manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have recently added a tag to my web application using google tag manager. I have published the latest changes to live site.  Unfortunately it is getting 404 because the JavaScript I have used is not correct. what I need to do now is to stop the published changes until I get the correct JS script. Does anybody know how I could undo a published change in GTM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. There is a side bar in google tag manager in which you can choose to edit your tags. what I did I chose the tag I wanted to disable then removed the pages I had already configured to be fired on. saved and published the new version. It did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have deployed multiple tags at once you could also have reverted to the lastest version of your tag container (top menu, "Versions", from the actions dropdown of the last correct version select "edit as new version").

Comment: Yes that works in case there are not more than one tag. In my case I have  more than one tag in that version so had to actually edit the tag and publish a new version